# I am trying to make a post request in a API from React but I get "net::ERR_ABORTED 415"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Here is the code and here is the web API that I am connecting to "https://hub.graphistry.com/api-token-auth/". I have tried to use axios but id doesn't help with the cors:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  async postData() {
    try {
      let result = await fetch("https://hub.graphistry.com/api-token-auth/", {
        method: "post",
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: "orlando",
          password: "graphistry1234",
        }),
      });

      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.postData()}>
          Press me to post some data
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use form-data as bellow:

```js
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", "orlando");
formData.append("password", "graphistry1234");

fetch("https://hub.graphistry.com/api-token-auth/", {
   method: "POST",
   body: formData
})
```

fetch() does not expect a JavaScript object at body. curl command and fetch() pattern are not the same.

Comment: don't mention it :)